# Can not find compilation library location for package when running ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I recently installed a NuGet package that references 'system.runtime.serialization.xml'.

I see the following in the console when installing the NuGet Package:

> Successfully installed 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml 4.3.0' to NuGetPackageThatIInstalled

When running the ASP.NET Core MVC app I get the following error:

> Can not find compilation library location for package 'system.runtime.serialization.xml'

Does anyone know what the cause of this error is? It seems that on another computer I can't reproduce this error. I am currently using .NET Core SDK 1.0.4 and latest version of VS2017.

Comment: did you call `dotnet restore`?

Comment: @Set yes, additionally I believe VS2017 constantly calls this when building.

Comment: Is this during F5/dotnet run?  Or do you get this when running the published app?  Can you try publishing the app and running it?

Comment: Did you recently install a 2.0 preview of the .NET Core?

Comment: @HenkMollema No, this was a while ago. It is fine now.

Comment: what did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: could you please tell me what did you do to fix the problem?